# Generate .c source from a .m (Objective-C) file

Tags: objective-c, gcc, clang

Is it possible to generate a C source file (.c) from an Objective-C source file (.m), using, maybe, GCC or Clang (or another tool)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you may be interested in the C++ rewriter. Given an objective-C file, let's say:

```
#import <stdio.h>
int main() {
    void (^blk)(void) = ^{
        printf("hi");
    };
    blk();
    return 0;
}
```

You can get a C++ version with

```
clang -rewrite-objc main.c
```

which is great to see how objective-C is implemented. Most of the file will be just C.

Some of the resulting expressions are dense. You'll need patience, C knowledge, and the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html). http://cdecl.org/ helps with small pieces.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I'm looking for.